# How to say "he was only joking with me" in french

Tags: argot

I'm trying to describe a situation where someone made me believe a story that was not true just to see my reaction. Something that in English I would say "He was only joking with me" or "he was fucking with me" (sorry, it's the best way I found to describe my intent in English).

How would one say that phrase in French in a form that the majority would understand the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use one of:

> Il me faisait marcher

or, closer to "fucking with me"

> Il se foutait de moi

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to point out that someone try to make you believe something, you can use :

- "*mettre en boite*" (somewhat informal)
- "*faire marcher*" (somewhat informal)
- "*mener en bateau*"
- "*se jouer de*"
- "*berner*" : could apply, but does not always conveys the fact that it is fun
- "*bluffer*" (yes, it is used in french)

The following proposals dismiss the fact that someone tries to make you believe a story, and only consider that someone makes fun of you, but beware of some differences :

- "*plaisanter avec quelqu'un*" means "joking with someone" (not mocking him/her)
- "*plaisanter quelqu'un*" means "making fun from someone", always in a friendly way
- "*se moquer de quelqu'un*" means "making fun from someone", not always in a friendly way
- "*moquer quelqu'un/quelque chose*" means "making fun from someone/something", not in a friendly way.
- "*se foutre de quelqu'un*" (slang) can be friendly or not.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst *il plaisantait* would mean *he was joking*, *il me taquinait* would be able to convey the idea that *he was joking with me*.

Answer (score 0):

You could say : Il ne faisait que plaisanter avec moi.

Answer (score 0):

Although the first two meanings of the reflexive verb “(se) **moquer** (de quelqu’un)” involve:

1) “ridiculing someone or something ” and

2)“dismissing the value of someone/thing,

[its third meaning](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_moquer/52546) (Tromper ou essayer de tromper quelqu'un, quelque chose avec désinvolture = To/try to deceive/mislead/trick/fool someone/thing in a casual manner) might offer a more polite alternative to the idea conveyed by “Il se foutait de moi” =

> “Il se moquait de moi”

Answer (score 0):

Il se jouait de moi

[se jouer](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_jouer/45012)

> Ne pas se laisser arrêter par quelque chose ou n'en faire aucun cas : Se jouer des lois, des difficultés.
>
> ***Littéraire***. **Tromper quelqu'un**, abuser de sa confiance ou de sa naïveté, **le rendre ridicule** : Je vous dis qu'il s'est joué de nous !

*Jouer* implies playing and/or tricking.

Answer (score -2):

Il m'a plaisanté pour observer ma réaction.